# Send array of data to mqtt node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, mqtt

I am trying to send an array of data by node to my mqtt server.

I have a receive function working but I cannot get it working in the other way.

```
  var message = new Array();
  message[0]  = 108;
  message[1]  = 11;
  client.publish("/topic", message, {
            retain: false,
            qos: 0
        });
```

But I get

```
[ERROR] TypeError: invalid data
```

I don't know how I have to declare the array to be able to fill all the data and send it. In my recevie function I get the message variable as an argument and I can read it like an array: message[x]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mqtt supports `Buffer` or `String`

to use typed Array you have to convert it to buffer
you can use this npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/typedarray-to-buffer

```
var toBuffer = require('typedarray-to-buffer')
  var message = [];
  message[0]  = 108;
  message[1]  = 11;
var arr = new Uint8Array(message)
arr = toBuffer(arr)

/*
arr.toString()  // '\u0001\u0002\u0003' 
arr.readUInt16BE(0)  // 258 
*/
// arr is a buffer now! 
  client.publish("/topic", arr, {
            retain: false,
            qos: 0
        }, function(){
  console.log("message published"));
```